# why the spring-data-MongoDB support is not fetch all nested child records with data?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have MongoDB Collection like follow

**MongoDB JSON:**

```
 {
        "_id" : "1",
        "_class" : "com.AColl",
        "BColDate" : {
            "BName" : "xx",
            "BFirstName" : "97908",
            "BList" : []
        },
        "CCollList" : [ 
            {
                "CId" : "1",
                "Cname" : "abc"
                "CList" : [ 
                    {
                        "S" : "N",
                        "Value1" : "",
                        "Val2" : "qq",
                        "Val3" : "ww1"
                    }
                ],
                "addres1" : "",
                "status" : false
            }, 
            {
                "CId" : "2",
                "Cname" : "abc"
                "CList" : [ 
                    {
                        "S" : "N",
                        "Value1" : "",
                        "Val2" : "qq",
                        "Val3" : "ww1"
                    }
                ],
                "addres1" : "",
                "status" : false
            }, 
            {
                "CId" : "3",
                "Cname" : "abc"
                "CList" : [ 
                    {
                        "S" : "N",
                        "Value1" : "",
                        "Val2" : "qq",
                        "Val3" : "ww1"
                    }
                ],
                "addres1" : "",
                "status" : false
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Java PoJo:**

```
 @Document(collection="test")
    class Test implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Indexed
        private String id;
        @Field("bbcoll")
        private BColl bbcoll;
        @Field("CCollList")
        private List<CCollList> CCollList;
    }

    class BColl implements Serializable {
        private String BName;
        private String BFirstName;
        private List<BList> bList;
    }

    class CCollList implements Serializable {
        private String CId;
        private String CName;
        private List<CList> bList;
    }

    class CList implements Serializable {
        private String S;
        private String Value1;
        private String Value2;
        private String Value3;
    }
```

**Java Code - Spring Data MongoDB query:**

```
Test col = mongoOperation.findOne(query, Test.class);
```

**Query Response**

The Spring data query execution response is as follow,

```
{
 "_id" : "1",
 "_class" : "com.AColl",
 "BColDate" :
 { "BName" : "xx", "BFirstName" : "97908", "BList" : [] },
 "CCollList" : [ 
 {
 "CId" : "1",
 "Cname" : "abc"
 "CList" : [
 { "S" : "N", "Value1" : "", "Val2" : "qq", "Val3" : "ww1" }
 ],
 "addres1" : "",
 "status" : false
 }, 
 {
 "CId" : "2",
 "Cname" : "abc"
 "CList" : [
 { "S" : null, "Value1" : null, "Val2" : null, "Val3" : null }
 ],
 "addres1" : "",
 "status" : false
 }, 
 {
 "CId" : "3",
 "Cname" : "abc"
 "CList" : [
 { "S" : null, "Value1" : null, "Val2" : null, "Val3" : null }
 ],
 "addres1" : "",
 "status" : false
 }
 ]
}
```

please refer **CList** response. I am able to receive a valid response for once section () other the CList section values are loaded as null value but in MongoDB i have values for this section. Why this error happen and any idea? This issue is I identified recently in the production and testing environment due to this issue now we are thinking alternative solution instead of relying on only mongo data.

**Questions:**

When I try to iterate the CList object value for the “Cid” =2/3/1 and the MongoDB collections list values are null but in MongoDB the values are existed (as per json) and list object are not null.

**Why this issue in spring-date-mongoDB (version 1.9)? 
otherwise, please let me know that this issue identified earlier?**

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Query: { "id" : "1"}, Fields: null, Sort: null

Comment: Do you mean: Query: { "_id" : "1"} ??

Comment: this is my json query to fetch data from MongoDB,

Answer (score 0):

After having a hard time reading through the issue it seems you have trouble naming your java classes and properties in a way that match the store values. Please use the `@Field` annotation to align property names to the ones used within the store.

Having that said property `bList` in class `CCollList` should be named `CList` as you have it in your store.

```
"CCollList" : [ 
        {
            "CId" : "1",
            "Cname" : "abc"
            "CList" : [
```

Other than that, please try to stick to language specific conventions it'll make the code much more readable and help others understand it quicker.

Comment: Thanks Christoph Strobl.

Comment: please refer query response section for more information